# Создание jar с зависимостями maven

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, jar

Есть проект, который использует зависимости Maven. Как этот проект упаковать в jar средствами Maven или IntelliJ

Если я использую maven

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>debug.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Test</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

и последующее

```
mvn clean package
```

то у меня создается два jar файла. Один `test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` с содержимым

```
test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
└───META-INF
    │   MANIFEST.MF
    └───maven
        └───debug.test
            └───test
                    pom.properties
                    pom.xml
```

содержимое манифеста:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: Anton
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_112
```

и второй файл `test-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` в который пакуются все зависимости (в данном случае это `log4j-core` и `log4j-api`), в манифесте указывается

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: Anton
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_112
Main-Class: Test
```

Но самого класса `Test` нет ни в первом jar, ни во втором.

Лог сборки прикладываю

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\java" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=D:\Anton\Sources\Java\Temp\Test "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=49597:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2018.1 clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ test ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\Anton\Sources\Java\Temp\Test\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Anton\Sources\Java\Temp\Test\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ test ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Anton\Sources\Java\Temp\Test\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ test ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ test ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ test ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: D:\Anton\Sources\Java\Temp\Test\target\test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (make-assembly) @ test ---
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/services/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/versions/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/versions/9/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/versions/9/org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache/logging/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache/logging/log4j/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/org.apache.logging.log4j/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/DEPENDENCIES already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/LICENSE already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/NOTICE already added, skipping
[INFO] Building jar: D:\Anton\Sources\Java\Temp\Test\target\test-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
[INFO] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/services/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/versions/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/versions/9/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/versions/9/org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache/logging/ already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache/logging/log4j/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/maven/org.apache.logging.log4j/ already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/DEPENDENCIES already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/LICENSE already added, skipping
[INFO] META-INF/NOTICE already added, skipping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.194 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-03T12:17:24+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/204M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Меня устроит и создание jar, через intelij. Делаю так

```
Project Structure -> Artifacts -> Add -> JAR -> From modules with dependencies
```

JAR тогда отлично создается, но проблема в том, что при изменении зависимостей IDE их сама не подтягивает в jar и приходится их редактировать вручную

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не хватало определения каталога исходников в pom файле

```xml
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
    ......................
</build>
```

Или нужно перенести исходники в папку `src/main/java`